# Hide specific files from toctree?

Tags: python-sphinx, glob, restructuredtext, toctree

I'm using a *readthedocs.org* instance on my localhost to build HTML documentation from my *github repo* and I would like to be able to do the following.

Currently I have a list of files being read by using toctree's glob feature like this:

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2
    :glob:

     *
```

But I need to avoid certain files to be listed in my toc, eg:

```
Test_Manuals.rst
Test_Process.rst
Test_Users.rst
Testing.rst       <--- Only this file should appear in the toctree, all others are listed inside this one 
Testing_on_test_dot_spy.rst
```

I have tried adding a `:hidden:` below the `:glob:` section but it just hides everything.

I have looked into as much documentation I could find but nowhere I have found an example when these two options are used together.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you just simple contstruct toctree manually instead of using *? In the worst case you need to write  a custom script snippet which outputs .rst itself :(

Comment: I want to allow developers to edit docs in github and have not to worry about toctree. It should use :glob: to index all available files but I want to hide some specific ones.

Comment: Maintaining manual doc tree is the easiest option in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I'm relatively new to Sphinx, so perhaps this is terrible Sphinx-etiquette, but I found this gave the desired behaviour without any warnings:

```
.. toctree::
  :glob:

  dir_to_glob/*

.. toctree::
  :hidden:

  dir_to_glob/file_to_hide
```

Throwing in a second `toctree` seems to overwrite how to handle `file_to_hide` without messing up anything in the glob. In this way you only need to maintain a "to exclude" list (which for me is small, and sounds like it may be for your case as well.)

Comment: This doesn't work in my scenario: my top-level toctree in `index.rst` contains `foo`, and `foo.rst` has your two-toctree thing in it. When I make html, `index.html` displays its toctree, and it contains all of the stuff that was in the full wildcard, not wildcard-minus-specifics. Edit: Putting the hidden toctree first didn't fix it either.